Modern CMake best practise: How to present and use public compile definitions of a Library
I have read a fair few articles and threads recently about following Modern CMake best practices and one common theme is that you should stay out of other libraries' flags.
I'm particularly attracted to the idea that you can simplify your dependency graph greatly if you avoid having clients of a library specifying the include directories and build flags of that library, instead opting to define all of that in the library itself and using PUBLIC PRIVATE and INTERFACE.
That way, a simple call to target_link_libraries(MyApplication PRIVATE MyLibrary) takes care of everything and keeps the dependency graph very simple.
In practise though, when I write a library, I may wish to make several features configurable i.e. so that they can be toggled on/off. I may also wish to expose certain compiler definitions to the client, for instance, setting pre-processor definitions like -DDEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE=48000 or perhaps -DSYSTEM_CLOCK_SPEED=200000000
How do I provide this level of configurability without having the client application touching any of the flags?
I read somewhere that you can think of your CMake library kind of how you think of C++ classes
class ExampleClass
{
private:
    // The members of the class are private to prevent clients
    // setting them directly    
    int Foo;
    bool Bar;
    std::string Baz;

public:
    ...
    // The setters defined here are part of the class's public API
    // that a client uses to interact with the private members
    void SetFoo(int foo) { Foo = foo; }
    void SetBar(bool bar) { Bar = bar; }
    void SetBaz(string baz) { Baz = baz;}   
};

If you think of the compiler definitions that you want to allow your clients to configure as private member variables, then you can define cmake functions/macros in a module.cmake in the library almost like a public API.
This is the closest thing I can see that will provide separation from the client and the flags but still give you some useful level of configurability. Am I completely missing the point here or is this a sensible approach?

Configuration parameters, which could be set by a user, are specified by using option or set(.. CACHE) CMake commands. Depending on those parameters you could set e.g. compiler definitions which will be used for your library.
